# Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I am getting the error message in the title on my login form in ASP.NET does anyone know what how i can sort it out? help is much appreciated

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim conn As New MySqlConnection

  conn.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;port=3307;user=user;password=password;database=DB;")

  Try

    Dim SQL As String = "select * from users3 where uname = '" & txtUName.Text & "' AND password = '" & txtPwd.Text & "'"

    conn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, conn)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        reader.Read()
        Dim isValidLogin As Boolean
        Boolean.TryParse(reader.GetValue(1), isValidLogin)

        If isValidLogin Then
            Session("UserName") = txtUName.Text
      Response.Redirect("REGISTERPROP.aspx")
    Else
      Response.Write("Invalid Login")
    End If

  Catch ex As Exception
    Response.Write("An Error Occurred: " & ex.Message.ToString())
  End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [conversion from string to type boolean is not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874049/conversion-from-string-to-type-boolean-is-not-valid)

Comment: the problem has been solved i think as i am not getting the error message anymore however am getting this now "Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()" am really weak on asp.net and help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please set this question to answered and ask a new question while posting your current code.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Dim isValidLogin = reader.GetValue(1)
```

to:

```
Dim isValidLogin As Boolean
Boolean.TryParse(reader.GetValue(1), isValidLogin)
```

Comment: Thanks, i am getting this error message now "Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()" do you have any ideas? i appreciate the help!

Comment: You still have the call to reader.Read(), right?  And this is still before the declaration of isValidLogin?

Comment: Yes it is, it looks like that:

Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

            reader.Read()
            Dim isValidLogin As Boolean
            Boolean.TryParse(reader.GetValue(1), isValidLogin)

            If isValidLogin Then
                Session("UserName") = txtUName.Text

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message is pretty much self-explanatory. You're trying convert an empty (nil) string into a boolean. The only valid string values for `Boolean` are (case-insensitive) `true` and `false`. You have other problems though.

- Your query returns 0 rows (the empty set) if the user/password is not found, and (presumably) 1 row if the user/password is found. However, you are not checking the return values from the `Read()` method: it returns `true` if a row was read and `false otherwise`. You query only returns a row on a successful match: You should check that prior to trying to retrieve data from it.
- Further, your query has a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability. Consider using parameterized queries or stored procedures. What do you think might happen if somebody types (or simply posts) this back to your page for the password field:

  ```
  ; drop table users3 ;
  ```
- It appears you're storing passwords in the clear in your database. In conjunction with your SQL Injection vulnerability, you leave yourself wide open to having your system and users compromised. Consider salting the passwords and hashing the salted password using a [secure hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) like SHA-256.

Change your query to

```
`select 'true' from user3 where ...`
```

And execute it using [`DbReader.ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns the first column of the first row of the result set or `null` if the result set is empty. Then your logic becomes simpler, something like

```
Dim isValidLogin = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
If isValidLogin IsNot Nothing And isValidLogin Then
  Session("UserName") = txtUName.Text
  Response.Redirect("REGISTERPROP.aspx")
Else
  Response.Write("Invalid Login")
End If
```

Comment: I know my code is prone to SQL injection and I will be attending to that after... my main goal is to get this login form to work i have to hand this is tomorrow at college and if i cant get it to work i'll fail, am stressing as i am weak on asp.net and i simply cannot get the form to work.. looking at my full code could you show me exactly what it should look like in order for it to work? You wouldn't believe how great full i would be!

Comment: I'm not a VB.Net guy, so I would be the wrong resource for you :D

Comment: thanks for the help anyway, its just depressing me now am not a coder myself so i find this really difficult especially when its affecting my grade :(